# how put text next to a table

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| c l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{legenda}} \\ \hline
1 & lampade \\
2 & rete radio \\
3 & controllore locale \\
4 & controllore centrale \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I'm trying to put text next to this table (top alignment), but I'm failing. To do what I want I tried to use these environments: `minipage`, `tabular` and `wrapfigure`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: use `\begin{tabular}[t]` to get top alignment then just add text as in `\end{tabular} some words here`

Comment: If you use wrapfigure or wraptable, it replaces \begin{table}...\end{table}.

Answer (score 2):

I used `\raisebox` to remove the gaps normally placed above and below the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}% automatically uses minimum width
\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][\dimexpr\depth-2\baselineskip]{% remove gaps above and below
\begin{tabular}[t]{| c l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{legenda}} \\ \hline
1 & lampade \\
2 & rete radio \\
3 & controllore locale \\
4 & controllore centrale \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: no gaps]